# Draggable and resizable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create div which are draggable as well as resizable.
Now, if I hardcode one div at design time, it works. However, if I add divs at run time, draggable does not work.

```
/*----------------------*/

. movingDiv { 
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
/*-----------------*/

.........
.........
 <div id="source">
</div>
<div id="container">    
<div class="movingDiv">
    <p>Drag and resize</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
  $("#source").click(function () {
      $("#container").append('<div class="movingDiv"></div>');
    });

  $(".movingDiv").resizable().draggable();
</script>
```

Comment: When you call `.resizable()` and `.draggable()` it only applies to items that exist at that time. You need to use event delegates. See link above

Answer (score 0):

You should make it:

```
$("#container").append('<div class="movingDiv"></div>').draggable().resizable();
```

This way `draggable()` and `resizable()` are called on each new div when its created not just once at the beginning of execution.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a working example of what @TimTheEnchanter already proposed:

```js
$("#source").click(function () {
  $("#container").append($('<div class="movingDiv"><p>Drag and resize</p</div>').draggable().resizable());
});
```

```css
.movingDiv { 
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="source">source</div>
<div id="container">    

</div>
```